# Remove duplicate substring from a string in oracle

Tags: regex, string, oracle, duplicates

I have strings like below in my table

2001,2452,2452,2421,2421,2495

2001,2483,2421,2421,2482

2001,2420,2421,2421,2425

2001,2420,2421,2421,2422

2001,2452,2452,2421,2421,2464

I want to remove the repeated numbers like 2452 and 2421 and show them only once in the data like

2001,2452,2421,2495

2001,2483,2421,2482

2001,2420,2421,2425

2001,2420,2421,2422

2001,2452,2421,2464

Has anyone done something like this? please let me know how to solve this

Thanks!

Comment: You should seriously consider moving away from storing CSV data like this.  Get each CSV value onto a separate row.

Comment: Is APEX installed in your database?  You could write your own but `apex_util.string_to_table` and `apex_util.table_to_string` and/or depending on APEX version `apex_util.split` and `listagg` could be used.  Assuming that fixing the data model isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle SQL, You can use the hierarchy query and `listagg` as follows:

```
select str, listagg(str_distinct, ',') within group (order by 1) as distinct_str from
(select distinct str, regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+',1,column_value) str_distinct from cte
cross join table( 
        cast(multiset( 
            select level lvl 
            from dual 
            connect by level <= regexp_count(str, '[^,]+')) 
        as sys.odcivarchar2list) 
        ) lvls)
group by str;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b36fb64fb5dbe5c891a88f83416b7a1e) for one of the input string.